# WampServer v2.5 Put Online 403 Error Forbidden

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wampserver

I downloaded wampserver to create our php application and I already setup my domain `thesis.dev` in my host file. My groupmates are working in our project and we share wifi from my modem router. I am trying to Put Online our project so that they can also access my project to view the created website but my friends are getting this:

> 403 Forbidden Error Message

This is my host file:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       project.dev

::1             localhost
::1             project.dev
```

and this is my httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:\wamp\www"
    ServerName  localhost
    ServerAlias localhost

    <Directory c:\wamp\www>
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "d:\Documents\Programs\Websites\thesis\public"
    ServerName  thesis.dev
    ServerAlias thesis.dev

    <Directory d:\Documents\Programs\Websites>
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My Apache version: 2.4.9. My MySQL version: 5.6.17. My PHP version: 5.5.12

My IP address is 192.168.1.2.

My friends are trying to access 192.168.1.2 on a browser but getting 403 error.

Comment: A 403 means you are accessing a resource you do not have permission to access. What do your error logs say?

Comment: This is the [apache_error.log](http://pastebin.com/vRB6T5GF)

Comment: (Try please to avoid external pasteboards if you can, and make changes to your post, not just in comments. Future visitors may not be able to follow the detail of the post if it is hidden in broken links).

Comment: OK, the warnings about non-existent domain names are worth fixing. Change the `ServerName` to domain strings that you do wish to use, or remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok a few things here

First remove these 2 entries from the httpd-vhost.conf file. They are just example entries provided to help people get started. If you note they point to folders you should not actually have i.e. `C:/Apache24` etc

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Secondly, when you start to use Virtual Hosts the `Put Online` and `Put Offline` become redundant. Your Apache security is now held within each VirtualHosts definition. So if you want to open your `thesis.dev` site up to others on your local network i.e. others sharing your router over wifi you need to tell Apache that thats allowed, so chnage this VH definition like so :-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "d:\Documents\Programs\Websites\thesis\public"
    ServerName  thesis.dev
    ServerAlias www.thesis.dev

    <Directory "d:\Documents\Programs\Websites">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
        Require ip 192.168.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Note I added this line

```
Require ip 192.168.1
```

as an example, all you need to do is check that your routers DHCP server is giving ip addresses in the subnet 192.168.1 Thats the norm for home routers but yours could be different.

Check yours by running this from a command line

```
ipconfig
```

Then check for this line

```
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.11
```

And use the first 3 of the 4 quartiles to allow anybody that is using your internal network access to the web site.